# When to allocate a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

When should I allocate a new thread to the task?

I have one task to compute 100k of equations and store the result into one array, and the second one to sort it. Should I stick to 2 threads, taking into account that I make it a thread-safe code, or can I assign like 3 threads to calculate one third of 100k equations and a fourth one to deal with sorting? Or just 2 threads?

Also, I have a 4 core processor, what happens if I bring the program with 4 threads onto another pc with 2 cores?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you should try it and profile it.

Comment: "Also, I have a 4 core processor, what happens if I bring the program with 4 threads onto another pc with 2 cores?"  Nothing out of the ordinary would happen, you would just have 4 threads running on a dual-core CPU, rather than 4 threads running on a quad-core CPU.

Comment: The frequency of the each thread's progress would be halved (I assume).

Comment: Take a look at ThreadPools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx

Comment: I highly recommend you go read the free ebook from Microsoft "[Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)", it explains a lot of concepts that are good to know when you are new to threading. For example, depending on what the equations do you may be doing too little work in the thread and the overhead costs will end up making it go slower than if you just did all 100K on one thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, having two threads for the two tasks you describe (calculating and sorting) is useless, since you can only sort the results when all calculations are done, assuming you want to sort by the results.

For the calculations themselves, it depends on the weight of the calculation. Threads allow you to execute them simultaneously, but you also got a little overhead. Having more than one thread on one core is slower than having just one thread, since you got the overhead of switching between thread, without the benefit of simultaneous execution.

Also, you will need a thread safe version of an array (or list), which might be a bit slower because it may to synchonise access to it.

So I think a better solution would be to store the results in one array per thread, let the threads calculate independently, and only after they are all done combine the arrays. I must admit I don't know if you can assign a single thread to a single core. If so, I would create one thread per core.

When dividing the calculations between the threads, don't cut the array in N equal pieces. It could be that one of your cores is very busy with a demanding thread from another process. If that is the case, then a thread of your process will get hardly any time. So it's better to assign small pieces, so if a thread is slower, it will just calculate less pieces of the source array. If you use a thread safe counter, each thread can just pick the next item after each calculation.

Comment: Thank you, so if I leave sorting for later, can I still split the 25k to a first thread, 25k to a second, a similar to the other 2 to build up the array of results as quickly as possible, or would I only require 1 thread to do all of that? (Assume the array and program is thread-safe) Thanks!

Comment: You could, but there's a risk in that, which I just added to the answer. But 100.000 equations sounds like it can be done really quickly. Introducing threads makes your code harder to write and to maintain, so if the single threaded calculation is fast enough, I wouldn't bother.